# Using List in recursive function call FizzBuzz

Tags: f#, f#-interactive, fizzbuzz

`As a learning Exercise with the FizzBuzz code in F#.`

Reference with code [here](http://metadeveloper.blogspot.com/2011/01/learning-f-with-fizzbuzz.html) is working fine and looks good

In above code I want to learn/use **match** instead of if conditions as below so have wrote below function which works for any given int value.

```
let fizzbuzz num =
   match num with
   | x when (x % 3 = 0 && x % 5 = 0) -> printfn "%s" "FizzBuzz"
   | x when (x % 3 = 0) -> printfn "%s" "Fizz"
   | x when (x % 5 = 0) -> printfn "%s" "Buzz"
   | _ -> printfn "%s" (num.ToString())
;;
```

output:

```
fizzbuzz 15;;
FizzBuzz
val it : unit = ()
```

However In my above code needed to use list as input and make function as recursive. how can I do it? I understand working of list i.e  using `h::t` and  pass `t` as recurisve to `fizzbuzz`. I am struggling with syntax i guess.

Appericate you guidance on how to use list (pattern matching and accumulator argument) in above code?

Is there any blog/reference on how to use F# Interactive window with less keystokes as  i found myself typing complete code again for any syntax error

Comment: @BLUEPIXY that is what I have suggested, read my answer below.

Comment: @Ramon Snir Yes, I meant to say no changes are needed.

Comment: which is  more readable syntax  - 1] List.iter fizzbuzz [1..10];;   or 2] [1..10] |> List.iter fizzbuzz;;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A bit more elegant solution than Daniel's, but same concept.

```
let fizzbuzz =
    List.iter (function
        | x when x % 3 = 0 && x % 5 = 0 -> printfn "FizzBuzz"
        | x when x % 3 = 0 -> printfn "Fizz"
        | x when x % 5 = 0 -> printfn "Buzz"
        | x -> printfn "%d" x)
```

And usage is same as with Daniel's solution:

```
[0..100] |> fizzbuzz
```

*Edit*: About the F# Interactive:

In general, I work with a script file and use Alt+' to execute code. This way I get syntax highlighting, design-time errors and IntelliSense.

When I do not have Visual Studio (and I don't like MonoDevelop, or whatever it is called), I use the command-line F# Interactive which has auto-complete (press `TAB`, it will auto-complete, press `TAB` again if you want different completion).

*Edit again*: Here is a solution with recursion and accumulator:

```
let fizzbuzz =
    let rec util acc = function
        | [] -> acc
        | h::t ->
            let h =
                match h with
                | x when x % 3 = 0 && x % 5 = 0 -> "FizzBuzz"
                | x when x % 3 = 0 -> "Fizz"
                | x when x % 5 = 0 -> "Buzz"
                | x -> string x
            util (acc + "\r\n" + h) t
    util "" >> fun x -> x.[ 2 .. ]
```

Example:

```
> fizzbuzz [1..15];;
val it : string =
  "1
2
Fizz
4
Buzz
Fizz
7
8
Fizz
Buzz
11
Fizz
13
14
FizzBuzz"
```

Answer (score 2):

For me, the point of the *fizzbuzz* task is to keep the solution as simple as possible to get the job elegantly done. Simple code is generally more readable and easy to maintain. Your function uses `match` nicely to solve the core part and you just need to add iteration to call it for numbers from 1 to 100. This can be done using `for` loop:

```
for i in 1 .. 100 do
  fizzbuzz i
```

The task is imperative, because it requires you to print to the console, so adjusting it to a more functional version (i.e. collect the results as strings, instead of printing). This is a good thing to try next, because then you'll either need recursive list processing or functions like `List.map` (trying to solve the problem using both ways is a good way to learn).

Comment: there are so many ways to solve a simple task in f#. How do you decide which way is better? are there any suggested guidelines in functional language world?

Answer (score 1):

```
let rec fizzbuzz = function
  | [] -> ()
  | h :: t ->
    match h with
    | x when (x % 3 = 0 && x % 5 = 0) -> printfn "FizzBuzz"
    | x when (x % 3 = 0) -> printfn "Fizz"
    | x when (x % 5 = 0) -> printfn "Buzz"
    | x -> printfn "%d" x)
    fizzbuzz t
```

Usage:

```
[0..100] |> fizzbuzz
```

[More options...](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2422697/162396)